# How can I execute Samba in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, samba, synaptic

I have to install Samba on my Ubuntu 14.04 from Synaptic. I have used the search box to search about "samba" and I have installed all packages that was linked to it.

After doing that I have checked that Samba was installed correctly with the following command:

```
dpkg -s samba
```

getting the following output:

```
Package: samba
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: net
Installed-Size: 11290
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
...
```

so I think it is installed correctly.

The problem I am having is that I do not know how to open it as a visual interface and not by commands because it is a requirement from my homework and I cannot figure out how to open it.

I tried going to the "Start" search box of Ubuntu 14.04 but writting "samba" nothing appears. I searched on the Internet about it but could not find anything useful for this version of Ubuntu.

What can I do to get the visual interface for Samba?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Samba itself runs once installed.

The GUI for samba configuration is called `system-config-samba`.  Depending on what desktop you use, it may show up under Preferences as Samba, or you may have to type the program name in as a command. In some cases you may need to install it.

[image]

In most installations I have tried, there is a bug in the way this GUI is installed, that keeps it from running.  Fortunately, the fix is very easy.  So if you try to start it and nothing happens, just enter this command in a terminal.

`sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf`

then try starting it again.

Comment: Yes, I meant to system-config-samba​ sorry. I already had installed it.But how can I start it?

Comment: Depending on what desktop you use, it may show up under Preferences as Samba, or you may have to type the program name in as a command

Answer (score 0):

Samba is a service used to accesses file shares, there is no "GUI" to open, you simply start the samba service, and then you will be able to acess SMB shares on your network.